# How many commands in PHP have the ; semicolon charcter

Tags: php, syntax

I am looking at making an application that edits a PHP file and adds a new line of code. I am using the ; semicolon as the the identify of a new line. So for example

```
 echo 'hello';
 $a = 'world'
 echo $a;
```

so, in this example my application would replace like this:

```
echo 'hello';
<custom code>
$a = 'world';
<custom code>
echo $a;
<custom code>
```

Now, my program takes into account anything inside quote marks, and single quote marks. But my question is what syntax does PHP have that contain semicolons ;. For example I know that the for look has semicolons example:

for(;;) << this i would have to take into account. Can you guys think of anymore?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use a newline character to define a new line?

The `;` could be anywhere in the code (not just at the end of the line).

Comment: I agree ";" could occur anywhere as a string. i.e. echo(';'); or $string =  'This is a string; I guess';

Comment: when I declare a large array or use method chaining, there are also newlines where a custom code, like the OP wants to insert, would throw an error!

Comment: I think that's a bad idea. For example, I split long if() statements or array declarations into multiple lines all the time.

Comment: @Alex -- you need a smart parser to know when that will and wont happen

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use the [`tokenizer`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php). Anything done with regex will be unreliable and very easy to break.